# How to unsubscribe from stripe payment plan using Stripe API in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, stripe-payments

i am able to subscribe on a package in stripe using Stripe API in c#, now my goal is to give user option to unsubscribe to the plan how can we do that using stripe API any code sample or classes which i can use ?

please find the detail below.

API : stripe.net

thanks do let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

To end an ongoing subscription, you need to use the [cancel subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription) API request.

This is the documentation to issue this request with Stripe.net: https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#canceling-a-subscription.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i still not able to identify the code in stripe.net